# How to replace windows prompt for username and password with custom sign in page in SharePoint 2013 claims authentication (windows NTLM)

Tags: sharepoint-server, windows-authentication

I am having a requirement to replace windows credential prompt with custom sign in page. I am using claims authentication with windows (NTLM).
So how to disable windows prompt and show custom sign in page?
And what should be the method to validate user with its winodws username and password ?

Answer (score 0):

Creating custom login pages for SharePoint 2013 still uses the same concept from SharePoint 2010

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2010/07/09/creating-a-custom-login-page-for-sharepoint-2010.aspx